# generate eigen images of an image matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

I am new to image processing and am trying to learn few concepts by practically implementing certain functions. I heard about creating eigen images of an image, so tried to implement the same, to actually know what they are and what properties they alter.

Thus I obtained the eigen vectors using the **eig** function in matlab. How can I display these eigen images using the vector? Please forgive me if the question is wrong or rudimentary. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please give a clear definition of eigenimages. Without that it is not a programming question.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I am sorry, but I am new. I came across a question for beginners and it asked me to compare the eigen images of an image. I am not sure of the definition of an eigen image and I thought its a common term that people in this field would know.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface ?  See: http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~sis26/Eigenface%20Tutorial.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have several images of size r x c, then taken the steps described on wikipedia, you should now have eigenvectors `ev1`, `ev2` ... of length r x c.

If this is the case, it should be fairly easy to turn these into images again:

```
myImage1 = reshape(ev1,r,c);
```

Check whether r and c are in the right order and whether you need to transpose, but this is basically it.

For showing them you may want to look into `surf` or `image`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have only one image to test. I found this to be more explanatory. http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/svd/node1.html